# How to modify font size Pyfiglet

Tags: python-3.x, termcolor

I'm trying to print some ascii text art in the terminal with python3 using the modules pyfiglet and termcolor, i was wondering if there is a way for modify the size of the ascii text that is printed.
RIght now i'm using this code for print the ascii art text:

```py
from termcolor import colored, cprint
from pyfiglet import figlet_format

color = 'yellow'
cprint(figlet_format('Ascii text'), color)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for reducing/increasing the size of the font, you can adjust the *width* parameter.

```
pyfiglet.figlet_format("Python", font = "doh", width = 100 )
```

width size:100

[image: width size:100]

```
pyfiglet.figlet_format("Python", font = "doh", width = 200 )
```

width size:200

[image: width size:200]

Answer (score 1):

I felt a need to change the font size while using the pyfiglet module. So I read the source code of figlet_format() but unfortunately, there is no such option in the code which let's user manipulate the font size. 
A workaround here is to better use some other font-style which is comparatively smaller than your current one.

Answer (score 1):

Hope there's no option for increase or decrease the font.
But definitely we have multiple styles available.

I was shocked to see the contributions from 1993's... for different Font..!
I have also given a link for font names and contributors..! (hope it will help you..!)

http://www.figlet.org/fontdb.cgi

please support me, if it's helpful for you and others too...

```
!pip install pyfiglet    
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
art = figlet_format('FOR FUN',font = 'doh')
print(art)
```